# Interfaces in C++-Header File

Tags: c++, interface, com, header-files, idl

Im supposed to write a C++-programm that interacts with a uEye camera.
For this I have to include several files, one of them being a header file that has around 30 interfaces in it that are like the one shown below. 
When I run a c++ programm including this header file, Im getting the error:

"error: expected identifier or '(' before ':' token"

at the first line (interface IuEyeAutoFeatures : public IUnknown) of every single interface in the header file.

Heres one of the interfaces from the header file:

```
interface IuEyeAutoFeatures : public IUnknown
{
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoBrightnessReference)(long lReference) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoBrightnessReference)(long* plReference) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoBrightnessMaxExposure)(long lMaxExposure) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoBrightnessMaxExposure)(long* plMaxExposure) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoBrightnessMaxGain)(long lMaxGain) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoBrightnessMaxGain)(long* plMaxGain) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoBrightnessSpeed)(long lSpeed) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoBrightnessSpeed)(long* plSpeed) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoBrightnessAOI)(long lXPos, long lYPos, long lWidth, long lHeight) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoBrightnessAOI)(long* plXPos, long* plYPos, long* plWidth, long* plHeight) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoWBGainOffsets)(long lRedOffset, long lBlueOffset) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoWBGainOffsets)(long* plRedOffset, long* plBlueOffset) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoWBGainRange)(long lMinRGBGain, long lMaxRGBGain) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoWBGainRange)(long* plMinRGBGain, long* plMaxRGBGain) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoWBSpeed)(long lSpeed) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoWBSpeed)(long* plSpeed) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(SetAutoWBAOI)(long lXPos, long lYPos, long lWidth, long lHeight) = 0;
    STDMETHOD(GetAutoWBAOI)(long* plXPos, long* plYPos, long* plWidth, long* plHeight) = 0;
};
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IuEyeFaceDetection, 
            0xe122a994, 0xfc4d, 0x445b, 0xb2, 0x1c, 0x30, 0x8b, 0x67, 0x48, 0x44, 0xe0);

#ifndef DS_EXPORT
#   define DS_EXPORT
#   ifdef _UEYETIME
#       undef _UEYETIME
#   endif
#   ifdef UEYETIME
#       undef UEYETIME
#   endif
typedef struct _UEYETIME
{
    WORD      wYear;
    WORD      wMonth;
    WORD      wDay;
    WORD      wHour;
    WORD      wMinute;
    WORD      wSecond;
    WORD      wMilliseconds;
    BYTE      byReserved[10];
} UEYETIME;
#endif  /* DS_EXPORT */

#ifndef DS_EXPORT
#   define DS_EXPORT
#   ifdef S_FDT_INFO_EL
#       undef S_FDT_INFO_EL
#   endif
#   ifdef FDT_INFO_EL
#       undef FDT_INFO_EL
#   endif
/*!
 * \brief uEye face detection info element data type.
 * Info on a single detected face as listed by \see FDT_INFO_LIST.
 */
typedef struct S_FDT_INFO_EL
{
    INT nFacePosX;              /*!< \brief Start X position.                                                               */
    INT nFacePosY;              /*!< \brief Start Y position.                                                               */
    INT nFaceWidth;             /*!< \brief Face width.                                                                     */
    INT nFaceHeight;            /*!< \brief Face height.                                                                    */
    INT nAngle;                 /*!< \brief Face Angle (0...360° clockwise, 0° at twelve o'clock position. -1: undefined ).  */
    UINT nPosture;              /*!< \brief Face posture.                                                                   */
    UEYETIME TimestampSystem;   /*!< \brief System time stamp (device query time) .                                         */
    UINT64 nReserved;           /*!< \brief Reserved for future use.                                                        */
    UINT nReserved2[4];         /*!< \brief Reserved for future use.                                                        */
} FDT_INFO_EL;
#endif  /* DS_EXPORT */

#ifndef DS_EXPORT
#   define DS_EXPORT
#   ifdef S_FDT_INFO_LIST
#       undef S_FDT_INFO_LIST
#   endif
#   ifdef FDT_INFO_LIST
#       undef FDT_INFO_LIST
#   endif
/*!
 * \brief uEye face detection info list data type.
 * List of detected faces, lists \see FDT_INFO_EL objects.
 */
typedef struct S_FDT_INFO_LIST
{
    UINT nSizeOfListEntry;      /*!< \brief Size of one list entry in byte(in).     */
    UINT nNumDetectedFaces;     /*!< \brief Number of detected faces(out).          */
    UINT nNumListElements;      /*!< \brief Number of list elements(in).            */ 
    UINT nReserved[4];          /*!< \brief reserved for future use(out).           */ 
    FDT_INFO_EL FaceEntry[1];   /*!< \brief First face entry.                           */
} FDT_INFO_LIST;
#endif  /* DS_EXPORT */
```

As far as I know, declaring interfaces using the word "interface" is done in languages like Java but not in c++, so I dont understand why this header file declares interfaces like this. Since this header file is provided by the company IDS after downloading their driver it should be correct i suppose.

How can I fix that bug and make my program work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `interface` is probably an unfortunate macro that is causing the error, grep for `#define interface` and you should find it.  If not then ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You can fix this bug and make your program work by learning C++, then investigating the contents of the header files, and with your newly-acquired understanding of C++'s syntax and grammar figure out which header files need to be included, in which order, in order to be able to work with this poorly-designed and organized software library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

`interface` is a preprocessor macro, commonly used with COM interfaces. It is defined in *combaseapi.h* as:

```
#define __STRUCT__ struct
#define interface __STRUCT__
```

You need to include that header file (either directly or indirectly through `#include <objbase.h>`) before including the interface header.